# Reopen request: How to compare two word files?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

Clicking on the [linked](https://superuser.com/questions/87285/how-to-compare-2-word-file) question below leads to a "Page not found". Can this question be re-opened, because the duplicate got deleted?

> **This question already has answers here**:
>
> Closed 10 years ago.
>
> > **Possible Duplicate:**
> > [Diff software for Word files](https://superuser.com/questions/14894/diff-software-for-word-files)

Comment: Done...........